# How to display two different columns data into one column using sql?

Tags: sql, pivot

I came across one situation where I'm trying to display two years of sales data for a products side by side. In that I need to display its variety as well in it.

The problem here is we have different varieties for different weeks. The requirement is to display both in one column and that should not effect the sales number.

here is the below example:

```
fy   fw fp prod   variety      salesamount
2016 1   1  Nike  Shoes          50$ 
2015 1   1  Nike  Hat            20$
```

I need to display it like below:

```
fy   fw fp prod   variety      salesamount    salesamount
2016  1 1   Nike  Shoes, hat          50$           20$
```

and if the variety are same then it should display one name.

Can you give me how to do this?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Even when the fiscal year is different? Or is that a typo?

Comment: I'm using SQL- Server

Answer (score 0):

Why would you put the `variety` in one column but the prices in another?

I suspect something like this might do what you want:

```
select max(fy) as fy, fw, fp, prod,
       max(case when fy = 2016 then variety end) as variety_2016,
       max(case when fy = 2015 then variety end) as variety_2015,
       max(case when fy = 2016 then salesamount end) as salesamount_2016,
       max(case when fy = 2015 then salesamount end) as salesamount_2015
from t
where fy in (2015, 2016)
group by fw, fp, prod
```

Comment: I kept variety in one column because they want to see the all the variety data in one column